# Why my JAVA_HOME points to Java 8 even though it has been set to Java 7?

Tags: java-home

Here's a picture that illustrates the problem perfectly:

[image]

I have restarted windows after changing that.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` does not indicate where the command line finds the `java.exe` - that's defined through the `PATH` variable

Comment: So edit your `PATH` variable and make sure it is pointing to your JDK 7.

Comment: One thing that's interesting is that he echos %JAVA_HOME% on the left side and it outputs 1.8.0 whereas on the right side in the Environment Variables it's set to 1.7.0

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Ok, the `PATH` has `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;` in it in the beginning. How to change the Java-version of that `javapath`?